# What is a good Javascript or Rails Spelling Checker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, spell-checking

Have you guys used any good spelling checker script?

I have tried JSpeller and AfterTheDeadline so far.

I am using RoR and Jquery. The language is pt-BR

Comment: You're asking this after trying AfterTheDeadline... does that mean you didn't like it? I'm curious about such things as well.

Comment: AfterTheDeadline is good, and it is probably enough for me. However I have seen some small problems on it. For example, it doesnt work if I change from a checked field to another checked field

Comment: what do you mean by "checked field"?

Comment: I mean a field that is being spell checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing some of these scripts, I chose `AfterTheDeadline`

- Best looking
- Good usability

Answer (score 1):

[jquery based spell checker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/)

Comment: It seems good, but I don't think it works with language pt-BR

Comment: OK, after bit of googling. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/wiki/Documentation suggets that you can install language packs on aspell and use. Aspell supports pt and br http://aspell.net/man-html/Supported.html, Also it suggest "Google" as an option, not sure if Google support pt-br